# How to deal with recycling lists

Tags: xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

I'm building a UI test suite for an iOS app using XCUITest api. The app uses recycle lists and I need to access specific cells of those lists during my tests as shown in the code below:

`let cells: XCUIElementQuery = app.descendants(matching: XCUIElement.ElementType.any).matching(identifier: "cells_accessibility_id")
let cell: XCUIElement = cells.element(boundBy: index)
cell.tap()`

My problem is that since this is a recycle list, as soon it scrolls by any reason during the test (like animations), cells are unloaded, "cells" won't return all items and then "index" won't get the right cell from the list or becomes out of bounds.

Is there another way that I can retrieve the whole list regardless of element visibility? Or do I have to change my tests/try another approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can not rely on the indices of reusable cells as you pointed out, however there is usually a way to eliminate the dependency on having to test cells at certain indices. The solution will depend on what you want to test, but here are some possible alternative strategies:

- If your table cells are always the same, you could give them each a hard-coded identifier based on their contents.
- If your table cells have dynamic content in them, you could use stub test data for each test to make it so that there is only one cell on screen (the one which is relevant to the test).
- If you can identify the cell you want by the views contained within the cell, you can search each cell for the relevant views before selecting it, instead of relying on its index.

Comment: what I'm testing is actually a content editor, so cells have no specific views to distinguish them, there's no way to hardcode ids and their content is created by the test itself. but anyway, I just want to be sure that "there's nothing I can do about it", so I can change my tests scope and move on (I'm new to test automation, btw)